# Can anyone help me with SQL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have three tables - TableA, TableB & TableC.
TableC is the merger of TableA & TableB. 
 
The table structures are as below:

TableA
SID Fname    Lname     Job               Grade  EndDate 
 
101 Rosy          Maria       Doctor            A3         06/10/2009 
 
102 Shane       Watson     Manager       A1         21/02/2010 
 
103 George       Michael Lawyer             A5         11/04/2015 
 
104 Stella        Kim           Teacher         A2      30/09/2007 
105 Amanda    Lee       Accountant    A4      15/08/2012

TableB
SID Dept       Grade  EndDate 
 
102 Finance A4         19/05/2012 
 
103 Legal       A1        28/02/2008

Table C
SID Fname    Lname    Job                     Dept          Grade   EndDate 
 
101 Rosy          Maria      Doctor               NULL       A3           06/10/2009 
 
102 Shane       Watson    Manager          Finance    A4           19/05/2012 
 
103 George       Michael    Lawyer            Legal      A5           11/04/2015 
 
104 Stella        Kim          Teacher         NULL       A2              30/09/2007 
 
105 Amanda    Lee           Accountant  NULL       A4            15/08/2012

Rules:
1. TableA.SID = TableB.SID 
2. TableC.EndDate = Earliest EndDate date from joined records from TableA & TableB 
3. TableC.Grade = Grade from the Earliest EndDate date from joined records from TableA & TableB

I have written sql many ways on TableA & TableB to get the result of TableC but couldn't get the correct result. So can you please help me with sql joining table A and table B using the key SID using the above rules.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not a question

Comment: Do you want to join table A and table B using the key SID and by picking the row from Table B with recent End Date to form Table C?

Comment: Yes. I need an sql joining TableA and TableB using the key SID.   <br/>  For EndDate field by picking recent EndDate field from  <br/>  TableA/TableB to form TableC EndDate field. <br/> For Grade field by picking Grade field for the recent EndDate field from  <br/> TableA/TableB EndDate

Answer (score 0):

JOIN two tables table A and table B using the ID field SID and in the SELECT list use CASE statements like

```
SELECT 
A.SID, 
A.FNAME,
A.LNAME,
A.JOB,B.DPT
CASE WHEN (A.ENDDATE > B.ENDDATE) THEN A.ENDDATE ELSE B.ENDDATE END 'ENDDATE',
CASE WHEN (A.ENDDATE > B.ENDDATE) THEN A.GRADE ELSE B.GRADE END 'GRADE' 

FROM TABLEA A
JOIN TABLEB B
ON A.SID = B.SID
```